# How to create 3 columns in HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to be able to display 3 colums with images, titles and buttons shown below. I know I am using split left and right but I am unable to create 3 columns on my own. I am using this for my portfolio, if you require anymore information or an example of my portfolio so you can understand what I would like then please do ask.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>`enter code here`
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Joe's Portfolio</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <header class="fix">
            <div class="nav-area">
                <ul class="menu-area">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="work.html">Coursework</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="future.html">Future Aspirations</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
                    <li><a href="cv.html">CV</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

                    <div class="banner-text-name">
                <h2>Joe Busby</h2>
            </div>

        </header>

            <div class="split left">
      <div class="centered">
        <img src="Assets/coding.png" alt="Online World">
        <h2>Website Developer</h2>
        <div class="svg-wrapper">
          <svg height="40" width="150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <rect id="shape" height="40" width="150" />
            <div id="text">
              <a href="web.html"><span class="spot"></span>Learn More</a>
            </div>
          </svg>
      </div>    
      </div>
    </div>




     <div class="split right">
          <div class="centered">
            <img src="Assets/shield.png" alt="Security">
            <h2>Security Analyst</h2>
            <div class="svg-wrapper">
              <svg height="40" width="150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <rect id="shape" height="40" width="150" />
                <div id="text">
                  <a href="web.html"><span class="spot"></span>Learn More</a>
                </div>
              </svg>
          </div>    
            </div>
            </div>
        </body>

        </html>
```

//CSS//

```
.split {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.left { 
  left: 0;
  background: #0F2027; 
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0F2027, #080e10);
}

.left h2 {
    color: aliceblue;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.right h2 {
    color: aliceblue;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  background: #0F2027; 
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0F2027, #080e10);
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.centered img {
  width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand why you can't change `50%` to `33.3333%`

Comment: @freefaller doing so does not change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could always use bootstrap as already said.
if you rather do it with pure css and html see `http://jsfiddle.net/a6yecjqb/4/`

```
.split {
  height: 100%;
  width: 33.33%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.center {
  left:33%;
  right:33%;
  background: #0F2027; 
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0F2027, #080e10);
}
```

if you change the width of split and add a center block you will get 3 div's in separate rows. if more explanation is needed let me know

Answer (score 0):

Why not using grid?

```
div.example {
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}
```

When you create elements inside that div, they will appear automatically in 33%

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using flexbox: here is a quick example:

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
}

.columns {
  padding: 5px;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: white;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.columns h2 {
    color: black;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.centered img {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>Joe's Portfolio</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    </head>

    <body>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="columns ">
      <div class="centered">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="Online World">
        <h2>Website Developer</h2>   
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="columns ">
      <div class="centered">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="Online World">
        <h2>Website Developer</h2>   
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="columns ">
      <div class="centered">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="Online World">
        <h2>Website Developer</h2>   
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

https://jsbin.com/xipeduxuda/